# Using docker to compose a remote image with a local code base for *development*

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have been reading this tutorial:

https://prakhar.me/docker-curriculum/

along with other tutorials, and Docker docks and I am still not completely clear on how to do this task.

**The problem**

My local machine is running Mac OS X, and I would like to set up a *development* environment for a python project. In this project I need to run call an api from a docker repo `bamos/openface`. The project also has some dependencies such as `yaml`, etc. If I just mount my local to `openface`, ie:

```
docker run -v path/to/project:/root/project -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 -t -i bamos/openface /bin/bash
```

Then I need to install `yaml` and other dependencies, and every time I exit the container the installations would be lost. Additionally, it is also much slower for some reason. So the right way to do this is using Docker compose, but I am not sure how to proceed from here.

---

**UPDATE**

In response to the comments, I will now update the problem:
Right now my `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda
ADD . /face-off
WORKDIR /face-off    
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt    
EXPOSE 5000    
CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

It is important that I build from `anaconda` since a lot of my code will use numpy and scipy. Now I also need `bamos/openface`, so I tried adding that to my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python app.py
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
        - .:/face-off
  openface:
    build: bamos/openface
```

However, I am getting error:

```
build path path/to/face-off/bamos/openface either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL
```

So I need to pass `bamos/openface` the right way so I can build a container with it. Right now `bamos/openface` is listed when I do `docker images`.

Comment: _Could I ask for a relatively detailed step by step instructions?_ No, that would probably come under "request for off-site resource" in the close reasons. Can you narrow it down at all? What are you actually stuck on?

Comment: Is it just that you want to preserve the state of your development environment when you stop the container? If so, you can map your project root in the container to the project root on your host. This sets up a container that points to your host's version of your project - it is not permanent of course, but you can set that up with a different run command.

Comment: If you need to install `yaml` - I assume that's a Python module - why not install that using your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @halfer I updated my question so it's more specific.